# Converting point cloud to raster with PDAL

Tags: pdal

I would like to convert my test.las file to a DTM file

I tried using this command:

- `(LIDAR) C:\Users\Dell\Documents\LIDAR>pdal pipeline test.json`

But it's giving me as an error:

```
(PDAL Debug) Debugging...
PDAL: Pipeline: parse error at line 1, column 1: syntax error while parsing value
- invalid literal; last read: '■'
```

I tried to test with another file.json, but I'm having the same problem.

here is my test.json:

```
{
    "pipeline": [
        "C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/DATA/lidar.las",
        {
            "filename": "RasterTEST",
            "output_type": "mean",
            "gdaldriver": "GTiff",
            "radius": "10*1.41",
            "type": "writers.gdal",
            "resolution": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your test.json is in the directory you're running your pdal command from.  I know using a nonexistant .json file gives the "parse error at line 1, column 1" message.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure the below link can help you.
https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2017/07/use-pdal-to-generate-dem-from-lidar-las.html

Comment: Link-only answers are likely to be removed, since links are likely to go stale. You can mention a link in a complete answer, but a link can't *be* the answer.